# Why is "An'im Zemirot" called "Shir Hakavod"?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, names, shabbat-songs, musaf

In most Siddurim (Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard) the hymn that starts with the words "An'im Zemirot" is denoted in the Siddur as "Shir Hakavod" - sometimes translated in English in the Siddur (such as Birnbaum) as "Hymn of Glory".

I surmise that because the words in the hymn contain many metaphoric praises of G-d, it got this name, but, I'm uncertain if that's the reason. How, when, and why did it get this name? Is this called something else (other than "Anim Zemirot") by any other group ?

Comment: Have you looked at the translation properly? 4 verses that in Hebrew begin Midei Dabri : Anim Z'mirot may be the first 2 words but doesn't really describe the song.

Comment: ...אדבר בך נכבדות...אספרה כבודך ...דברי בכבודך

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found in [Siddur Kol Tefilos Hashana - Philadelphia 1905](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43018&st=&pgnum=177&hilite=) - that it is called Shir Hakavod since it speaks about the honor of the creator -  Hashem.

Comment: Thanks. I have never seen this Siddur - prob. b/c it's out of print. I like it's "interlinear" translation. Would you have any idea if there's a way to obtain this old Siddur?

Comment: Try http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/ - you can also request one and when it is available they will let you know.

Comment: @DanF You can print it out of hebrewbooks.

Comment: @DanF, my grandfather ז”ל had a copy. I never looked beyond the first page, because I don't really like that type of layout for a siddur.